# Problem changing a class to a function and adding additional animation in react native

Tags: react-native, function, class, animation, react-animated

I am having issues trying to convert a class into a function and then adding another animation.

It has this :

```
   this.state = {
      rotateValueHolder: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
```

Now, that clearly is a state but how do I set it up in a function? Is it something like :

```
const rotateValueHolder  = new Animated.Value(0);
```

The thing is it get updated later and I am not sure how to change this  :

```
  startImageRotateFunction = () => {
    Animated.loop(Animated.timing(this.state.rotateValueHolder, {
      opacity: 1,
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 4000,
      easing: Easing.elastic(4),
      useNativeDriver: false,
    })).start();
  };
```

Because I have no setrotateValueHolder I cant just use this can I?

```
Animated.loop(Animated.timing(rotateValueHolder, {
```

The whole code is below is there is anything else I am missing. I am also wanting to add another animation to run with this, can I make another one and initiate them both at the same or different times or even after each one? The tutorials I have found are all so different it is difficult to understand,

Sorry if this seems easy but I am very new to react native and can not seem to grasp it.

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rotateValueHolder: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    
  }
  startImageRotateFunction = () => {
    Animated.loop(Animated.timing(this.state.rotateValueHolder, {
      opacity: 1,
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 4000,
      easing: Easing.elastic(4),
      useNativeDriver: false,
    })).start();
  };



render(){
    return(
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View>
          <Animated.Image
            style={{
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              alignSelf:"center",
              transform:
                [
                  {
                    rotate: this.state.rotateValueHolder.interpolate(
                        {
                          inputRange: [0, 1],
                          outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
                        }
                      )
                  }
                ],
            }}
              source={{uri:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/old_logo.png',}}
          />
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => this.startImageRotateFunction()}>
            <Text style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
              CLICK HERE
            </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you check out the docs yet? (https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated), and did you try running the code for functional yet? `useRef` is recommended so you can simply do `const rotateValueHolder = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current` and use `rotateValueHolder` as is.

Comment: Oh great will try it and what about this bit rotate: this.state.rotateValueHolder.interpolate( , do I use the useRef again? Thanks

Comment: Read more about `useRef` here (https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useref.asp). `useRef` is just a hook that helps persist values without causing re-renders. So, again, you can use `rotateValueHolder` as is: `rotateValueHolder.interpolate({ ... })`

Comment: Hi, Thanks, yep it works with what you said, now I will try with the animation stuff, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Harrison I got it to work, thanks and if anyone else has the same problems, the working code is below:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import {   
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  } from "react-native";

const App = () => {

const rotateValueHolder = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current
   
startImageRotateFunction = () => {
    Animated.loop(Animated.timing(rotateValueHolder, {
      opacity: 1,
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 4000,
      easing: Easing.elastic(4),
      useNativeDriver: false,
    })).start();
  };  
   
      return(
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View>
          <Animated.Image
            style={{
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              alignSelf:"center",
              transform:
                [
                  {
                    rotate: rotateValueHolder.interpolate(
                        {
                          inputRange: [0, 1],
                          outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
                        }
                      )
                  }
                ],
            }}
              source={{uri:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/old_logo.png',}}
          />
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => startImageRotateFunction()}>
            <Text style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
              CLICK HERE
            </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  fadingContainer: {
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: "powderblue"
  },
  fadingText: {
    fontSize: 28
  },
  buttonRow: {
    flexBasis: 100,
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    marginVertical: 16
  }
});

export default App;
```